# CSR8510 A10 Bluetooth Driver compatablity with Windows 10 pro

Tags: bluetooth, runtime-error, csr, windows-10-desktop

I have a PC with Windows 10 Pro without an embedded Bluetooth hardware. I have bought CSR8510 A10 dongle for that cause and currently the PC doesn't identify him (it used be before I formatted this PC). I tried to update it's driver and I have received

"
Windows found drivers for your device but encountered an error while attempting to install them. Generic Bluetooth Radio. The system cannot find the file specified.
"

I believe it is related to a problem with my Windows Update because there are 8 missing important security and quality fixes (according to Windows Update) and the computer cant install them due to error 0x800703e3.

When I tried to download the drivers and install them it didn't help and even when I installed CSR driver from the official website I have received a runtime error (of C++), "Program: C:\Windows\system32\regsvr32.exe  R6034"

What should I do next?

Comment: how did you fix this